# Why is winsound.PlaySound not playing the sound from the specified file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, winsound

I made a Morse code translator which works fine. Then I wanted to make beep sounds corresponding to the encoded message. I tried the `winsound` module. But it isn't playing any sound. I collected the dots and dashes sound from an
[online Morse Code Translator](https://morsecode.world/international/translator.html). The sound works fine if played by audio player. But it doesn't work with `PlaySound()`.

```
from winsound import PlaySound
import pyperclip as pc

morse_code_dictionary = {'A': '.-', 'B': '-...',
                         'C': '-.-.', 'D': '-..', 'E': '.',
                         'F': '..-.', 'G': '--.', 'H': '....',
                         'I': '..', 'J': '.---', 'K': '-.-',
                         'L': '.-..', 'M': '--', 'N': '-.',
                         'O': '---', 'P': '.--.', 'Q': '--.-',
                         'R': '.-.', 'S': '...', 'T': '-',
                         'U': '..-', 'V': '...-', 'W': '.--',
                         'X': '-..-', 'Y': '-.--', 'Z': '--..',
                         '1': '.----', '2': '..---', '3': '...--',
                         '4': '....-', '5': '.....', '6': '-....',
                         '7': '--...', '8': '---..', '9': '----.',
                         '0': '-----', ', ': '--..--', '.': '.-.-.-',
                         '?': '..--..', '/': '-..-.', '-': '-....-',
                         '(': '-.--.', ')': '-.--.-', ' ': '/', '': ''}

morse_code_to_alphabet_dictionary = {
    x: y for y, x in morse_code_dictionary.items()}

md, mad = morse_code_dictionary, morse_code_to_alphabet_dictionary


def valid_morse(message):
    char_code_list = message.split(" ")
    return all(char_code in mad for char_code in char_code_list)


def encode():
    text = input("Please input your text here.\n=")
    result = ""
    try:
        for char in text.upper():
            result += md[char] + " "
    except KeyError:
        result = "invalid charecter input!!!"

    return result


def decode():
    code = input("Enter your code here.\n=")
    result = ""
    if not valid_morse(code):
        result = "Your code was not valid or not in my knowladge. Please try again!!!"

    for single_char in code.split(" "):
        result += mad[single_char]

    return result.capitalize()


while True:
    ask = input(
        "Do you want to encode or decode?\nTo encode press 1\nTo decode press 2\n=")

    if ask.isdigit():
        ask = int(ask)

        if ask not in [1, 2]:
            print("Invalid inpput!!!\nTry Again!!!")
            continue

        elif ask == 1:
            result = encode()

        elif ask == 2:
            result = decode()
    break


print(result)
print("Result copied in ClipBoard")
pc.copy(result)

path = "*/"

for i in result:
    if i == ".":
        PlaySound(path+"morse_dot.ogg", 3)
    elif i == "-":
        PlaySound(path + "morse_dash.ogg", 3)
    elif i == "/":
        PlaySound(path + "morse_dash.ogg", 3)


 input("Press Enter To Exit()")
```

Comment: Can you play any sound at all with `PlaySound`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 No, I can't. I winsound or "playsound" module doesn't work at all.

Comment: What did you intend the `, 3` to mean?

Comment: @mkrieger1     amm... at first I got this error **"TypeError: PlaySound() missing required argument 'flags' (pos 2)"** .  so I tried to give the second parameter, value  "4" or "2" threw error. **Value 2 = "Runtime Error: Failed to play sound"** and **value 4 = "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'"**    and **"0"** just played **default windows error sound** so I used **"3"**..    I don't exactly know what this parameter called "flags" do....  I didn't find any docs about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You passed `3` as the *flags* parameter for `PlaySound` which amounts to `SND_ASYNC | SND_NODEFAULT`. <sup>(1)</sup>

This combination of flags doesn't make sense in your case.

- By `SND_NODEFAULT` you are telling `PlaySound` to omit the default sound if playing the sound file failed. This is bad because you don't notice if playing any sound works at all.
- `SND_ASYNC` isn't needed in your case.

Since the first argument you have passed is a filename, you have to use the flag `SND_FILENAME`.

In the simplest case you should be able to use `PlaySound(path+"morse_dot.ogg", winsound.SND_FILENAME)` (after adding `import winsound` at the top).

If this plays a default "beep" sound then you know that `winsound` is able to play a sound, but it couldn't play the sound from the file you have specified.

One reason this could fail is that `*/morse_dot.ogg` isn't a valid file path. Did you mean `./morse_dot.ogg`? Another reason might be that the documentation states that `PlaySound` plays WAV files, but you specified an `.ogg` file.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> The numeric values of the flags aren't listed in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winsound.html) but you can easily get them with a line of code: `import winsound; print({k: v for k, v in vars(winsound).items() if k.startswith('SND_')})`.